# Sort file using pipe in perl

Tags: perl, pipe

I am looking for a way to sort a file using pipe. I have checked different examples online but I am still confused

Let's say I have a file called "perlRocks.txt" with different names I want to sort.

This is what I have so far:

```
open(SORT, "| sort>perlRocks.txt") or die "Can't sort";
close (SORT);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening pipe for writing. If you already have this file you probably want read content sorted. See the example with `$in` below. If you want to write something from your script instead see example with `$out` below. See [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) documentation for more variants. For sorting existing file, you have to write to a new file and then rename. It's best to use some shell for this task.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constant FILE_NAME_IN => 'perlRocks.in';
use constant FILE_NAME_OUT => 'perlRocks.out';

open my $in, '-|', 'sort', FILE_NAME_IN;

while (<$in>) {print};

open my $out, '|-', "sort >'@{[FILE_NAME_OUT]}'";

print $out $_, "\n" for qw(foo bar baz quux);
```

There is safer version for output pipe which avoids problems with shell interpretation of FILE_NAME_OUT content (You can escape this content but ... no.)

```
open my $out, '|-' or do {
    close STDOUT;
    open STDOUT, '>', FILE_NAME_OUT;
    exec 'sort' or die $!;
};
```

If you insist you don't want to use shell, you can use Perl.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use constant FILE_NAME_IN  => 'perlRocks.txt';
use constant FILE_NAME_OUT => 'perlRocks.txt';

# don't bother with fork if you don't want continue with Perl process
my $pid = fork;
die "cannot fork" unless defined $pid;
unless ($pid) {    # use just this code inside in this case
    close STDIN;
    close STDOUT;
    open STDIN, '<', FILE_NAME_IN;
    unlink FILE_NAME_IN if FILE_NAME_IN eq FILE_NAME_OUT;
    open STDOUT, '>', FILE_NAME_OUT;
    exec 'sort' or die $!;
}
waitpid( $pid, 0 );
```

Note `FILE_NAME_IN` and `FILE_NAME_OUT` can be same, but it is not in-place sorting anyway. There are both versions of the file at the disc in some time even one can be hidden and inaccessible. There is also good [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) module for this sort of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use a pipe, use [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)  instead:

```
system("sort perlRocks.txt");
```

This will invoke the system command `sort` and give it `perlRocks.txt` as parameter. You will see the output of `sort` in the shell from which you invoked your script.

Of course, with just this command, the sorted content will be shown and then be forgotten. This might or might not what you have in mind. If you want to permanently store the sorted lines you need to redirect the output into another file.

Of course, perl comes with its own [sort](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) operator, so that you don't have to use an external sort command: `sort @lines`. In order to get the content of your file into `@lines`, you might want to use the module [`File::Slurp`](http://search.cpan.org/~uri/File-Slurp-9999.19/lib/File/Slurp.pm):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Slurp;

my @lines = read_file('perlRocks.txt');

print sort @lines;
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't using perl to sort. To do this in perl, you would want to:

```
open ( my $input_fh, "<", "perlRocks.txt" ) or die $!;
my @lines = <$input_fh>;
print sort @lines;
```

What you're doing is trying to call the command `sort`.

Comment: There's no reason to call the shell in order to do a sort -- even if the file has a few million lines, most modern computers should be able to handle this without any problems.

Comment: @DavidW. And can you simply use multicore for sorting in the Perl, in this case? Sorry, there is second decade of 21. sentury out there.